# What sort of function would accurately model the change in daylight at sunrise or sunset?

Tags: visible-light

Assume that you are standing on the equator in a flat, wide-open space and there is no moon or clouds.

What sort of mathematical function would accurately model the increase in daylight when night turns to day, or the decrease when day turns to night?

Would it be a sigmoid function? Or would it be something more linear?

Comment: What *exactly* (in more technical terms) do you mean by 'the increase in daylight'. You need to establish some measure.

Comment: here's data from Hong Kong http://www.hko.gov.hk/wxinfo/ts/display_element_solar_e.htm

Comment: Maybe just the [sunrise equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunrise_equation)?

Comment: "increase in daylight" is a terribly imprecise thing. The most obvious component is "what fraction of the sun is visible", which has a geometric component (slice of a circle) confounded with an optical component (refraction by the atmosphere). And then there is the "light of dawn" - the increased brightness of the sky which depends a lot on how clear the air is (scatter from aerosols). Could you be more precise about the factors you want included, and what the desired accuracy is? Maybe explain _why_ you are asking?

Comment: An accurate model would take into account the moon, clouds, and non-flat terrain. Even without those, it is complex. Light is absorbed by the long path through the atmosphere at a shallow angle. Blue light is preferentially scattered. The density and temperature of the atmosphere change with altitude, which affects the path of light rays. These are different over the desert vs areas with vegetation vs the ocean. Google green flash.